# Find linear independent vectors approximately

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, vector-spaces

Given a set of vectors $a_1,…,a_n∈Z^m$ ($n,m > 10^5$ and $a_i∈Z^+ $ and about $n/2$ elements are zero). How can I approximate orthogonal vectors without using inner product? What vectors' features should I use? In other word, I want to find linear independent vectors from this set without using inner product.

Is there any way to produce a similar, eventually just approximate, result is less time? I just need reasonable good candidates, then I can validate them and compute "proper" one.

P.S. I want to select some proper vectors from $a_1,…,a_n$ and then check whether these vectors are orthogonal or not. ex. suppose that $a_1, a_3, a_5$ are proper according to their features and then I will test that realliy they are orthogonal or not.

Comment: Not clear what you want.  You say you want to "approximate orthogonal vectors."  Do you mean that you want to turn the given set into a set of orthogonal vectors with the same span?  Or do you mean something else?

Comment: No, I want approximate vectors that are orthogonal without using inner product. Only use vectors' features. something like equal zero norm, nonzero elements that have same location in vectors, ... but I don't know what features show better  
intuition for orthogonality

Comment: It's still not clear to me what you're looking for. It sounds like you need some sort of approximate test for orthogonality that does not use an inner product.  I understand that much, but it's not clear to me what the set of vectors $a_1, \ldots, a_n$ has to do with this, or what you want to do with those vectors, or if those vectors are somehow necessary for constructing this approximate test.

Comment: Actually I want to select some proper vectors from $a_1,…,a_n$ and then check whether these vectors are orthogonal or not by using inner product. ex. realize that $a_1$, $a_3$, $a_5$ are proper according to their features and then I will test that realliy they are orthogonal or not (assume that equal number of nonzero element is best feature for approximating orthogonality, here). Hope This is clear now.

Comment: Now posted to MO, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/153295/find-linear-independent-vectors-approximately where it will probably be closed soon.